# Deeplink not working properly when i set pathPrefix

Tags: android, xml

> My code

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

<data android:scheme="http" />
<data android:scheme="https" />
<data android:host="www.mywebsite.com" />
<data android:pathPrefix="/?mypage.php" />
```

My deeplink is not working while im using special characters on pathPrefix

Comment: `?` is not merely a special character. It is not part of the path. It signifies the beginning of the query parameters. You cannot filter on query parameters in an `<intent-filter>`.

Comment: so how do i solve a deep link that uses the query parameter

Comment: You remove the `?mypage.php` from the `pathPrefix`, and then you get the query parameter value from the `Intent` that your activity receives.

Comment: Do you have any reference?

Comment: https://newbedev.com/how-to-access-and-pass-parameters-to-the-modules-of-an-android-instant-app demonstrates the process -- while it is in the context of Instant Apps, the general approach works for all apps.